# how to give HTML5 validations into hidden label when the submit button is clicked in JSP?

Tags: java, html

I am using html5 validation for my form in jsp page. I have given novalidate in form. When i click on submit button of that form it should validate the form now and display all validation in one label which was hidden before.How can i get these in jsp?
This is my form code.

```
<form action="#join1_form" method="POST">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" required placeholder="First Name" pattern="\w+" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="" required placeholder="Last Name" pattern="\w+" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" id="email" value="" required />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" required placeholder="New Password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w{6,}" name="password" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Password must contain at least 6 characters, including UPPER/lowercase and numbers' : '');
if(this.checkValidity()) form.cpassword.pattern = this.value;">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="cpassword" id="cpassword" type="password" placeholder="Re-enter Password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w{6,}" name="cpassword" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Please enter the same Password as above' : '');">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="label" hidden value="">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

I want to display all the validation notes after submitting the submit button.These validations should displaye in textfield which is given hidden here.how can i do that?

this is my code for not repeating the emailID. where should i put this in above form?How to display its validation in the textfield which is given hidden above?

```
<%
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement ps=null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root", "");
String email1=request.getParameter("lemail");
try{
  String q="SELECT * FROM userdetails where email=?";
  ps=conn.prepareStatement(q);
  ps.setString(1,email1);
  rs=ps.executeQuery();
  if(rs.next())
  {
    //what to do here?
  }
  else
  {
    //what to do here?
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
try{
  if(ps!=null){
    ps.close();
  }
  if(rs!=null){
    rs.close();
  }
  if(conn!=null){
    conn.close();
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

Comment: @barnee what have you edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html:form action="storenotes" onsubmit="return demo()">
```

call demo() function in your JavaScript
and submit form by
return true
or
return false